# Call UI thread in HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, windows-phone, httpwebrequest

Good night, I'm trying to call the UI thread, to update a proprety actualy, inside `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse` method by using `CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync` method. But it does not work, I do not know how it works actually. There is my code:

```
private void DebutReponse(IAsyncResult resultatAsynchrone)
    {
        HttpWebRequest requete = (HttpWebRequest)resultatAsynchrone.AsyncState;
        Stream postStream = requete.EndGetRequestStream(resultatAsynchrone);

        string donneesAEnvoyer = "username=" + Name + "&password=" + Password + "&email=" + Email;

        string lol = donneesAEnvoyer;
        byte[] tableau = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(donneesAEnvoyer);
        postStream.Write(tableau, 0, donneesAEnvoyer.Length);
        postStream.Close();
        requete.BeginGetResponse(FinReponse, requete);
    }

    private void FinReponse(IAsyncResult resultatAsynchrone)
    {
        HttpWebResponse aResp = null;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest requete = (HttpWebRequest)resultatAsynchrone.AsyncState;
            WebResponse webResponse = requete.EndGetResponse(resultatAsynchrone);
            Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string reponse = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            stream.Close();
            streamReader.Close();
            webResponse.Close();

            //ErrorGridHeight = new GridLength(0.3, GridUnitType.Star);
            ErrorMsg = msgSucceed;
         }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            if (e.Response != null)
            {
                aResp = e.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            }
        }
        if (aResp != null)
            await errorFunc();
    }

    private async Task errorFunc()
    {
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => ErrorMsg = msgFailed);
    }
```

I have an error telling me that I can only use the `await` operator inside an `async` method who return a `Task`. I have no idea how it works.

EDIT:
Ok so I changed my code a little bit to avoid the problem of this function:

```
requete.BeginGetResponse(FinReponse, requete);
```

because she want a function with a specific prototype so I did this:

```
private async Task lol(IAsyncResult resultatAsynchrone)
    {
        HttpWebResponse aResp = null;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest requete = (HttpWebRequest)resultatAsynchrone.AsyncState;
            WebResponse webResponse = requete.EndGetResponse(resultatAsynchrone);
            Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string reponse = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            stream.Close();
            streamReader.Close();
            webResponse.Close();

            //ErrorGridHeight = new GridLength(0.3, GridUnitType.Star);
            ErrorMsg = msgSucceed;
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            if (e.Response != null)
            {
                aResp = e.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            }
        }
        if (aResp != null)
            await errorFunc();        
    }

    private void FinReponse(IAsyncResult resultatAsynchrone)
    {
        Task.Run(() => lol(resultatAsynchrone));
    }

    private async Task errorFunc()
    {
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => ErrorMsg = msgFailed);
    }
```

The only problem is that it does not change the proprety, it does not go into the set of my proprety. And I have an exeption which is:

> System.NotImplementedExeption

Thank you for the help.

Comment: "I have no idea how it works" Then it's perhaps a bad idea to ask a question here. Better first try to understand async/await by reading online documentation, tutorials etc.

Comment: Yes I just watched it, https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh191443.aspx but I'm not sure to totally understand all the step in the exemple. I wanted to practice to maybe undeerstand better.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `errorFunc()` to this.

```
private void errorFunc()
{
    CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        ErrorMsg = msgFailed;
    });
}
```

I also found another place, where you're trying to change `ErrorMsg` witouth calling the UI thread. It's the line with code `ErrorMsg = msgSucceed;`. I suggest to use the same way, so replace the line with this:

```
CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    ErrorMsg = msgSucceed;
});
```

Comment: Before I used this method, but now I change of project, I'm not sure exactly what it is, like Silverlight app maybe and I don't have this PERFECT method BeginInvock anymore. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `FinReponse` method `async` to be able to use `await` operator into it:

`private async void FinReponse(IAsyncResult resultatAsynchrone)`

Comment: Yes I tried it but I think I can not change it because this method:
`requete.BeginGetResponse(FinReponse, requete);`  need, think, a specific prototype, and it does not fit.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer to access the UI, I have to use:

```
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>mym());
```

and it works perfectly.
Thanks for everythings.